# Not able to access hidden field value post Jquery 3.3.1 upgrade in javascript

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

We have used Knockout library along with JQuery in our web application. We are binding a hidden field with a value from model in a CSHTML page:

```html
<input id="Item" type="hidden" value="@Json.Encode(Model.OrderList.Select(it => new { it.ItemDescription, it.ItemId}))" />
```

Then we're reading the value in JS and assigning to an observable like:

```
self.OrderList(JSON.parse ($("#Item").val()));
```

Before upgrading the jQuery library it was working perfectly fine but post jQuery upgrade, `$("#Item").val()` does not return anything but `undefined`.

Just after the upgrade, and without any further change, it started failing. Can you please tell me what needs to be changed in code?

On further diagnosing, I identified, this issue is only happening in pop up screens. I think there is some issue with ajax method.

Comment: Check the console to see what the error is that's being caused by the new version of jQuery.

Comment: I think `self.OrderList(JSON.parse() ($("#Item").val()));` must be a typo, as it will always throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes it was a typo. I am getting javascript runtime error - Invalid character. When I try to check the value of $("#Item").val(), it returns undefined.